# Shell Script doesn't color multiline <<EOF statement

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm working with a shell script in VSCode,
I'd like to be able to collapse the function.
In order for me to do that, the 'EOF' word has to have some whitespace before it.

But if I put whitespace before it, the entire coloring of the file is ruined (including all the functions appearing thereafter)

Is there a setting / or another way to do it so it will not behave like this?

Thanks

[With EOF word at the beginning of the line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cA1lr.png)

[With some whitespace before the EOF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7LbOj.png)